# format string syntax: printing percentage with at least one significant digit

Tags: python, formatting, python-3.x

I want to format a number as a percent, with at least 2 digits after the decimal point; and in addition, with at least one significant digit.

For example, I want 0.123456 to look like '12.34%'; and 0.00000123456 to look like '0.0001%'.

Is there a simple way to achieve that?

The reason is that my standard output should be a fixed point number with 2 decimals after the point; but if the number is so small that it looks like 0.00%, I need to show at least one significant digit so it can be distinguished from true 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap the percentage in a class, you can do things in its **format** method and still use it for normal calculations. You can also parse the arguement to **format** (the part between : and } in '{1:3}', to override the at_least value:

```
import sys
import math

class Percentage(float):
    _at_least = 2
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._x = val

    def __format__(self, s):
        #print 's [%s]' % (repr(s))
        at_least = Percentage._at_least
        try:
            at_least = int(s)
        except:
            pass
        return '{1:.{0}%}'.format(max(at_least, int(-math.log10(self._x))-1), 
                                  self._x)

for x in (1., .1, .123456, .0123, .00123, .000123, .0000123, .00000123):
    p = Percentage(x)
    print '{0} {1:3} {2}'.format(x, p, 50 * p)
```

Outputs:

```
1.0 100.000% 50.0
0.1 10.000% 5.0
0.123456 12.346% 6.1728
0.0123 1.230% 0.615
0.00123 0.123% 0.0615
0.000123 0.012% 0.00615
1.23e-05 0.001% 0.000615
1.23e-06 0.0001% 6.15e-05
```

You can do some more clever parsing for at_least to also specify field width, alignment etc.

Answer (score 9):

```
import math

def format_percent(x, at_least=2):
    return '{1:.{0}%}'.format(max(at_least, int(-math.log10(x))-1), x)


for x in (1., .1, .123456, .0123, .00123, .000123, .0000123, .00000123):
    print x, format_percent(x, 2)


1.0 100.00%
0.1 10.00%
0.123456 12.35%
0.0123 1.23%
0.00123 0.12%
0.000123 0.01%
1.23e-05 0.001%
1.23e-06 0.0001%
```

More cases with different `at_least`:

```
>>> format_percent(.1, 3)
'10.000%'

>>> format_percent(.012345678, 5)
'1.23457%'

>>> format_percent(.000123, 0)
'0.01%'

>>> format_percent(1.23456, 0)
'123%'
```

Comment: +1 - very neat solution. Didn't realise you could nest format specifiers like that. Minor note - you need to ``import math`` before using this.

Comment: I assume when I actually need to use in a large `print` statement, I have to do this: `print('The answer is {} out of the total'.format(format_percent(fraction)))`? Presumably there's no way to extend the standard `{}` language to add this particular format?

Comment: You might want to check for zero and negative values to avoid `ValueError: math domain error` exception.

Comment: Also, sometimes the value printed out is 0.000010%. Is there any way to avoid the final zero?